# How to make my animation work after my page if fully loaded

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want my page text to fadein from bottom and i am using https://animate.style to achieve that fadein animation to my text, But i only want it to animate 2secs after the loading screen is fully loaded...firstly i gave the element i container of my text display none so as not to display it b4 my desired time. and then I tried using jquery `setTimeInterveal()` function to make is show after a timeout but it only shows without animations.... Below is the code i tried.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $("#landed").css("display", "block");
  $(".products").addClass("animate__fadeInUp animate__slow");
}, 2000);
```

```css
#landed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing" id="landed">
  <!-- <span class="num-count num-1">1</span> -->
  <figure class="animate__animated soft">Softkodes</figure>
  <div class="product-contain">
    <h3 class="products animate__animated">
      We make Products that works
    </h3>

    <h6 class="lorem">
      We’re based in Nigeria but <br /> working worldwide, Partnering with local and international clients that value design just as much as we do
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="adds-service">
    <a href="#">Training</a>
    <a href="#">Design</a>
    <a href="#">Development</a>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down-wrap">
    <i class="line"></i>
    <i class="arrow-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am using https://animate.style to add animations after the time-interval but it doesn't work...It only display block and every content shows without animations....Please anyone with a possible idea to achieve this. An example can be found in http://obys.agency...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetInterval will repeat your function every two sec. You shold use setTimeout to delay excecution.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("#landed").css("display", "block");
      $(".products").addclass("animate__fadeInUp animate__slow");
},2000)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLko1bjp/

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp